# Call getFragmentManager() without extending Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a class that is handling a database in my Android app. When the database changes, I'd like to update the fragment displaying the information from the frogment. My approach has been to give the fragment a tag and then find the fragment with the following code:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag("Schedule");
        if (fragment instanceof ScheduleFragment){
            ScheduleFragment fr = (ScheduleFragment)fragment;
            fr.scheduleUpdated();
        }
```

However, as long as my database class is not an extension of Fragment, the compiler refuses to recognise `getFragmentManager()`. To me it makes no sense to extend Fragment, as the database class is no fragment, but a simple helper class to manage the database. Is it possible to get a reference to my fragment without extending Fragment? Or is this bad practice and should be done in another way?

Also, is it possible to get a reference to the fragment from a static method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a localBroadcast manager. when database changes laumch a Broadcast intent.  registere this  in "Schedule" Fragment and you can handle the database changes.
Refer to this link for more about LocalBroadcast Manager 
[how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html